# How can I print keys from json on my webpage one by one?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I wrote the following php code:

```
$q3 = $conn3->prepare("SELECT c.text as key1, c.timeframe as key2, p.date as key3 FROM table1 c, table2 p WHERE c.id = p.c_id");
$q3->execute();

if ($q3->rowCount() > 0)
{
    $check3 = $q3->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $arr = array();
    foreach ($check3 as $row) {
        $arr[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode(array('result'=>$arr)); 
}
```

and it returns me the json string in a form:

```
{
    "result": [{
        "key1": "aa",
        "key2": "15",
        "key3": "2015-04-12 18:50:00"
    }, {
        "key1": "bb",
        "key2": "30",
        "key3": "2015-05-09 11:26:38"
    }, {
        "key1": "cc",
        "key2": "45",
        "key3": "2015-04-12 18:50:20"
    },
```

etc.
Now I want this result to be printed on the other webpage, so first I included there the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction () {
        $.getJSON('list.php', function(json) {
            jQuery.each( json.result, function( i, subresult ) {
                console.log(subresult);
            });
        });
    }

    var interval = setInterval(function () { 
        myFunction(); 
    }, 60000);
</script>
```

and after running that webpage I see the results in the console - every minute I invoke the getJSON method and print in the console returned results. So I basically see the json string in the console. However, I would like to print each string on the webpage one by one - in the same div with e.g. fade in/fade out effect. For the example above I would like to see `"aa"` for 15 seconds, then `"bb"` for 30 seconds and `"cc"` for 45 seconds (the duration is stored as key2 value).

I added the interval above because after one minute I want to fetch another data from mysql database and also print it instead the old data, and so on.
Can you help me with that?
Thanks!

Comment: Your final question and question title are not the same. A bit misleading. It seems you are really asking how to add json values to a div instead of keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution for you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var results;
    var cursor = 0;

    function myFunction () {
        $.getJSON('list.php', function(json) {
            results = json.result;
            cursor = 0;

            // Now start printing
            printNext();
        });
    }

    function printNext(){
        if(cursor == results.length){
            // Reset the cursor back to the beginning.
            cursor = 0;
        }

        // Print the key1 in the div.
        $('#divTarget').html(results[cursor].key1);

        // Set a delay for the current item to stay
        // Delay is key2 * 1000 seconds
        setTimeout(function(){
            printNext();
        }, results[cursor].key2 * 1000);

        // Advance the cursor.
        cursor++;
    }

    var interval = setInterval(function () { 
        myFunction(); 
    }, 60000);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to fade in and fade out smoothly this text on the screen?

Comment: `$('#divTarget').hide('fast', function(){     $('#divTarget').html(results[cursor].key1);
$('#divTarget').show('fast');
});`

Comment: @randomuser1 replace `$('#divTarget').html(results[cursor].key1); ` with the line in above comment to fade in and fade out smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

i am creating a demo div where you can append the result one by one for each object

```
<script>
  function myFunction () {
       $.getJSON('list.php', function(json) {
          jQuery.each( json.result, function( i, subresult ) {
              $("#demodiv").append(subresult);
          });
       });
  }

  var interval = setInterval(function () { myFunction(); }, 60000);
</script>


<body>
<div id="demodiv" ></div><!-- This is the div where the result will be appended -->
</body>
```

**Edited:** as per you additional requirement:

```
k = 1; //these are global variables
multi = 15;
times  = '';
function myFunction () {
       $.getJSON('list.php', function(json) {
          jQuery.each( json.result, function( i, subresult ) {
              $("#demodiv").append(subresult);
              times = multi*k;
              k++;
          });
       });
  }

  var interval = setInterval(function () { myFunction(); }, times);
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how can I present the content to the user based on the duration of the string (key2 value)? For example I would like to show string `aa` for 15seconds, `bb` for 30seconds and `cc` for 45 seconds...

Comment: check the edit part, now can run the timer as multiple of 15 or any other value mulitple by replacing the value

Answer (score 0):

Change code to this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction () {
       $.getJSON('list.php', function(json) {
          jQuery.each( json.result, function( i, subresult ) {
              $("#divId").append(subresult);
          });
       });
  }

  var interval = setInterval(function () { myFunction(); }, 60000);
</script>
```